# Integrating Autoit to selenium: Getting value of variable in AutoIT code in Selenium script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit

My requirement is to automate configuring an instance(instance of my company product I am working on). The scenario is such that in the middle of my configuration, the control goes from window to browser and the rest of the configuration process is handled in the browser and so the entire process is a combination of window-based and browser-based. I have used AutoIT to complete the window-based configuration and when the control goes to the browser, I am using `_FFStart() $ffUrl = _FF_GetCurrentURL()`. I am getting the URL in a variable in AutoIT script. I want to automate the further web-based configuration through Selenium. I am calling this AutoIT compiled script from my Java class. 
My question is that is there a way in which I can get the URL that I am saving in my AutoIT script so that I can create a web driver instance, open the browser with the URL and further handle my configuration process using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

if you start/run an exe file from your code you can path variable as argument
something like:

$va = "my variable"
run("myexe.exe $var)

or equvivalent

or generally:

You can share variables between appliations/processes many ways

- using windows messaging look up _WinAPI_PostMessage function that sends message the specific window or broadcast message to all windows so all running app gets the message (2 variables can also be passed) in autoit you can set up a function that runs (stoppping the main program) when your autoit app receives such message and variables
- you can set up UDP or TCP channels so that your running apps can communicate (UDP should work fine) one app being the server the other is the client
- file communication setup, where the variable or information to be sent is written to a file and the other app reads the file (it can be good to combine with the first method: App 'A' writes data to file 'data.msg' then sends message to App 'B' that upon receiving the message reads 'data.msg') you can establsih intricate protocol as well with Acknowladge messages etc. in case your application requires it.

_WinAPI_RegisterWindowMessage
_WinAPI_PostMessage
GUIRegisterMsg

are the relevant functions you can look them up in autoit help

If you think any of these is feasible but you need further assistance I can write a simple code that demonstrates that in practice